# Getting a simple parameter from the URL before proceeding

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Imagine visiting one of these URLs:

/blog

/blog?page=5

Visiting /blog correctly gets the page number of 1. However, visiting a page like /blog?page=5 initially shows page as 1 and then correctly as 5.

How can this be changed so that it doesn't initially show the incorrect value? You cannot seem to use async await with the router.

Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated, thanks.

```
import {useRouter} from 'next/router';

const SomeComponent = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const page = router.query.page || 1;
    
  console.log('page', page);
    
    // rest of component would go below...
```

Comment: What do you mean initially shows as 1 and then 5?

Comment: I mean the console logs 1 initially, and then logs 3. Presumably this is because `router.query.page` is undefined until the query finishes, which would make the `page` variable temporarily 1 when visiting `/blog?page=5`

Comment: That's a common misunderstanding, see https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/11484
You need to wait for parameters to be ready. This is because Next.js is an SSR framework, so the query is never there at the first render. During the first render, your app rehydrate the server renders, so it doesn't yet know about the URL. Then the second render can start using browser API (current location, window etc.).

Comment: True, although in this case the solution on that page does not work for me because if someone visits just `/blog` then the result of `router.query.page` will always be undefined

Comment: If the URL is `/blog` it has no query params, so it's expected that `router.query.page` should always return `undefined`. To add to @EricBurel's comment, this behaviour only happens if the page doesn't have data fetching requirements. See [`next/router`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#router-object)'s `query` property documentation for details.